# How to display logged in username on the screen | express session

Tags: express, authentication, session, express-session

I want take the user info like email , username and display it on dashboard.ejs . i tried req.session.username and req.body.username but never worked . please help me in this !!
i want handle profile management for the web so by retriving the username help fetch the info about the user in the database

`

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoDBSession = require("connect-mongodb-session")(session);
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserModel = require("./models/user");

const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/sessions";

mongoose.connect( mongoURI, {
    useNewUrlParser : true,
    // useCreateIndex : true,
    // useUnifiedToplogy : true
}).then((res)=>{
    console.log("MongoDB connected");
})


const store = new MongoDBSession({
    uri : mongoURI,
    collections : "mySessions"
})

const isAuth = (req,res,next)=>{
    if(req.session.isAuth){
        next();
    }else{
       res.redirect("/login");     
    }
}

app.use(session({
    secret : "key that will sign a cookie",
    resave : false,
    saveUninitialized : false,
    store : store
}))

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    res.render("landing");
});

// Login Page
app.get("/login", (req,res)=>{
    res.render("login");
} );

app.post("/login", async(req,res)=>{
    const {email , password} = req.body;

    const user = await UserModel.findOne({email});

    if (!user){
        return res.redirect("/login");
    }
    const isMatch =await bcrypt.compare(password , user.password);
    if(!isMatch){
        return res.redirect("/login");
    }

    req.session.isAuth = true;
    res.redirect("/dashboard");
});

// Register Page
app.get("/register", (req,res)=>{
    res.render("register");
});

app.post("/register", async (req,res)=>{
    const {username , email , password } = req.body;
    let user = await UserModel.findOne({email});
    if (user){
        return res.redirect("/register");
    }

    const hashPsw =await bcrypt.hash(password,12);

    user = new UserModel({
        username,
        email,
        password:hashPsw
    });
    user.save();
    console.log("saved");

    if (!user){
        return res.redirect("/login");
    }
    const isMatch =await bcrypt.compare(password , user.password);
    if(!isMatch){
        return res.redirect("/login");
    }

    req.session.isAuth = true;
    res.redirect("/dashboard");
    
    
});

// Dashboard Page
app.get("/dashboard", isAuth , (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.session);
    res.render("dashboard");
});

app.post("/logout", (req,res)=>{
    req.session.destroy((err)=>{
        if (err) throw err;
        res.redirect("/");
    })
});

app.listen(3500 , ()=>{
    console.log("server running on port 3500");
})
```

`

Answer (score 0):

One of the options would be to supply that in the `POST` request's response. For example, Author has inserted it in a pug view [here](https://github.com/Zircoz/express-locallibrary-tutorial/blob/b98a97371118fd30a583387c7b339a62e7c2c567/views/profile.pug#L9) like   `h2 Username: #{user.name}` and has supplied it as variable while page rendering in response [here](https://%20%20res.render(%27profile%27,%20%7Btitle:%20%22My%20Profile%22,%20user:%20req.cookies.userData%7D);) with   `res.render('profile', {title: "My Profile", user: req.cookies.userData});`.

Since you have used ejs instead of pug, the injecting I did with `#{}` can be done with `<%= YOUR_VARIABLE %>` . Please, see [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-js-variables-accessible-to-ejs-files/) for a tutorial and [ejs docs](https://ejs.co/#docs) for more examples.